# Weird behavior while Suppress "Bookmarks" button in SAPUI5, Fiori

Tags: html, sapui5, sap-fiori

Some times ago i've successfully [suppressed](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ca.scfld.md.controller.BaseDetailController.html#setHeaderFooterOptions) the "Save as Tile" button that exists in the Standard Fiori App, MM_PO_APV:

```
// Standard application buttons (Remove Forward)
    this.setHeaderFooterOptions({
        oPositiveAction: {
            sI18nBtnTxt: that.resourceBundle.getText("XBUT_APPROVE"),
            onBtnPressed: jQuery.proxy(that.handleApprove, that)
        },
        oNegativeAction: {
            sI18nBtnTxt: that.resourceBundle.getText("XBUT_REJECT"),
            onBtnPressed: jQuery.proxy(that.handleReject, that)
        },
        onBack: jQuery.proxy(function() {
            //Check if a navigation to master is the previous entry in the history
            var sDir = sap.ui.core.routing.History.getInstance().getDirection(this.oRouter.getURL("master"));
            if (sDir === "Backwards") {
                window.history.go(-1);
            } else {
                //we came from somewhere else - create the master view
                this.oRouter.navTo("master");
            }
        }, this),
        // Remove the 'Save as Tile' button
        bSuppressBookmarkButton : true
    });
```

But they had updated the SAPUI5 version, I think the lastest, and it comes with a problem. The button is appearing, but with a weird behavior, as you can see:

[image: weird behavior]

All my code remains the same, and as I've seen on documentation API, it remains the same too.

Could you help me on how to resolve this?

Regards,

Andre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *most likely* cause for this would be the UI5 version(the latest update that you mentioned).
Try one of these two things,

- Clear cache and re-run the application
- Revert to a previous UI5 version or update to a new version

Contact the respective support team(Scaffolding team I assume) if these don't help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
//Prevent overflow button (...) in footer 
this.oApplicationImplementation.oDHFHelper.oCommonHeaderFooterHelper.bAutomaticOverflow = false;
```

Put this code in the `onInit` method of the controller extension.